# New Qt Application not running: tons of errors came up all of a sudden

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've been working for a short while on a Qt Appliation with Qt Creator, recently updated it to latest version, and suddenly it stopped working. I debugged for quite some time before I created a brand new project, ran it without making any changes to it and found out it also shows the same error messages as my ongoing project.
I can't tell for sure that this started happening right after the update, but it's very likely. And I don't recall making any configuration changes.

These are screenshots of some of the errors I'm getting on the brand new project:

[image: errors on IDE]

[image: errors on IDE]

System information:

```
Qt 5.12.0 (i386-little_endian-ilp32 shared (dynamic) release build; by MSVC 2015) on "windows" 
OS: Windows 10 
Architecture: x86_64; features: SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
Qt Creator 4.8.0
Based on Qt 5.12.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
From revision d51ddbb8f0
Built on Dec  3 2018 13:08:16
```

I'm really confused here.

Comment: I am confused. I see mingw includes (by the path) in the errors on the first picture and Visual Studio 2015. You should not be using anything mingw with VS2015.

Comment: Not sure what that means... I do have visual studio 2013 installed on the same computer, but it's been like that for ages and it never seemed to cause any trouble. I've been working on Qt Creator for quite a while on different projects and it never complained like this. It's indeed very strange.

Comment: Check your compiler setup in Qt-creator.